# Cleaning data scraped with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've built a couple of scrapers in python 3.6 using scrapy.

However, I am often getting messy data with strange symbols like `Â` in them. I also have an occurrence of the whole tagline being returned rather than the text. E.g. this:

> h3 class="matrix-heading short clear-hide"Â /h3,h3
>   class="matrix-heading clear-hide"Â /h3,h3 class="matrix-heading
>   long"51 Week

Has been returned from this code:

```
response.xpath('//div/section/div/h3/text()').extract()
```

I don't understand why it is returning the whole tagline as it is only returning the text in the scrapy shell.

Comment: Python works with unicode, maybe if you print() the extrected value you are fine.

Comment: Can you give the URL of the page you are trying to crawl?